# Pyspark dataframe parquet vs delta : different number of rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, delta-lake

I have data written in Delta on HDFS. From what I understand, Delta is storing the data as parquet, just has an additional layer over it with advanced features.

But when reading data with Pyspark, I get a different result if dataframe is read with `spark.read.parquet()` or `spark.read.format('delta').load()`

```
df = spark.read.format('delta').load("my_data")
df.count()
> 184511389

df = spark.read.parquet("my_data")
df.count()
> 369022778
```

As you can see the difference is quite big.

Is there something I misunderstood about delta vs parquet?

Pyspark version is `2.4`.

Comment: Not sure what and how you have written the data into the delta table, but you might see the difference in pure counting due to old versions of the data. I guess there is a reason why you should read delta tables with `format("delta")` and not through `parquet`, otherwise there is no sense in using delta table at all?

Comment: parquet is exactly twice that of delta: you have two versions of delta there that's the reason

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most probable explanation is that you wrote into the Delta two times using the `overwrite` option.  But Delta is versioned data format - when you use `overwrite`, it doesn't delete previous data, it just writes new files, and don't delete files immediately - they are just marked as deleted in the manifest file that Delta uses.  And when you read from Delta, it knows which files are deleted, or not, and read only actual data. Actual deletion of the data files happens when you're performing VACUUM on Delta lake.

But when you read with Parquet, it doesn't have information about deleted files, so it reads everything that you have in directory, so you get twice as many rows.